# sqlite3: using two columns in a row to make a calculation

Tags: python, sqlite

[Image of the database I am working with...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERLhx.png)

I am currently practicing with a database of NBA players. Related fields include **name**, **active**, and **games**. I am trying to create a temporary table containing **name** and **games_per_year (active/games**).

Firstly, I filtered the original database to players with 11+ active years, which I have successfully completed.

Now I am unsure how to create the temporary table consisting of name and games_per_year. Ultimately, I want to order this temp table by games_per_year and return the top 6 player names.

Here is my attempt at coding below. As you can see, I am a bit lost...

```
def most_games_per_year_for_veterans():
    """Top 6 players that are > 10 years active, that have the
       highest # games / year"""

    player_list = cur.execute("SELECT name, active, games FROM players 
    WHERE active > 10").fetchall()

    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS active_vets
        (name TEXT,
        games_per_year REAL)''')

    for player in player_list:
        # Create a tuple? Just a guess...
        player = (player[0], player[2]/ player[1])

        cur.executemany('INSERT INTO active_vets VALUES (?,?)', player)
```

Critique is welcome, if you have any resources that have helped you in the past, I would love to read them. I have found it difficult to find the answers I need online.

Comment: Use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` for temporary tables. You can also combine INSERT with SELECT: `INSERT INTO temp.active_vets SELECT name, games/active FROM players WHERE active > 10` (Though a view or normal select is probably better than a temp table).  There's tons of information and documentation on the [sqlite website](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

Comment: why not just do this directly as an `sql` script?